# Android OS and application

Tags: android

I am new to android.I want to know what all the devices that works on android OS.please help me out and thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

See this list of Android devices:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_devices

Answer (score 0):

I think all manifacturers in the Open Handset Alliance will support Android
http://www.openhandsetalliance.com/

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. This is n't a programming question but still If you want to start developing applications for android os .. go through the android.com .. They have a huge treasure of resources pertaining to android.